# c++ map erase(), iterator printing erased element

Tags: c++, stl

Why the output of following code is `b 0`:

```
int main ()
{
  std::map<char,int> mymap;
  std::map<char,int>::iterator it;

  mymap['a']=10;
  mymap['b']=20;
  mymap['c']=30;
  mymap['d']=40;
  mymap['e']=50;
  mymap['f']=60;

  it=mymap.find('b');
  mymap.erase (it);                   // erasing by iterator
  std::cout << it->first  << " " << it->second << std::endl;
  mymap.erase ('c');                  // erasing by key

  it=mymap.find ('e');
  mymap.erase ( it, mymap.end() );    // erasing by range

  // show content:
  for (it=mymap.begin(); it!=mymap.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << it->first << " => " << it->second << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `mymap.erase (it);` At this point `it` becomes invalidated.

Comment: Sir, what do you mean by invalidated ? and when i shift the cout to after mymap.erase('c') it prints '0 0'

Comment: @CerealKiller it means the current value of `it` becomes unusable. You cannot use it in the `cout` line as you did.

Comment: "Invalidated" means its value shouldn't be used, and a program that nevertheless attempts to use it exhibits [undefined behavior](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). Which is what your example does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iterator (it) points to a specific memory address in mymap. Once you call mymap.erase(it), that memory address no longer exists in mymap, so the iterator becomes invalidated and should not be accessed until it is reinitialized.

In your case, the iterator ended up returning 0. However it could have just as easily ended up returning 3, or 99, or -244242 or any other different store of memory that was already used. That's why you never want to access an iterator after it has become invalidated because it results in undefined behavior.

```
it = mymap.find('b');
mymap.erase(it); 
std::cout << it->first  << " " << it->second << std::endl; // this is not allowed!!!
```

If you need to access the value after erasing it from mymap, you should copy it into a variable first.

```
it = mymap.find('b');
std::pair<char, int> temp = *it;
mymap.erase(it);                   // erasing by iterator
std::cout << temp.first << " => " << temp.second << std::endl;
```